# The direction of the datalist's options does not change in Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I can not change the direction of the datalist's options to RTL.

The direction of the input element changes as expected, but not the direction of the options of the datalist.

I've tried setting the `dir` attribute to `rtl` and it has no effects.

I've also tried testing different styles that usually work for the select element, but none of them seems to work for the datalist

```html
<input list="myData" dir="rtl">
<datalist id="myData" dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl !important">
  <option value="first_value">Some RTL Description</option>
  <option value="another_value">Another Thing Here</option>
  <option value="first_second_third">More Stuff</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: It is working fine for me on latest version for Chrome.

Comment: working fine on windows 10, chrome Version: 83.0.4103.61 (Official build) (64-bits)

Comment: My chrome version is 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: And as I've pointed out in the questin, the text input is RTL, however the options are not.

Comment: It works in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in latest updated chrome 84.3. If I select something from the dropdown of your code text appears aligned-right and if I try to type something text gets typed from right to left. might be your browser.

If you mean your text is not shown as right to left in the dropdown, that is because u need to align your text as "text-align:right;" the input where you type stuff works RTL.

try adding the following line instead of your regular `<html>` opening

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
```

remember that datalist element is not fully supported in most browsers, and chrome might have a RTL problem with this particular element.

if you change the tagname of the element the RTL works in all browsers, the moment you do datalist element things are weird atleast in chrome, firefox seems works perfect, even tough Chrome is the one that "fully supports it"

Comment: Thanks for the answer; yes i want the dropdown text to be RTL, but the align-right style doesn't work, and I've tested a bunch of different style rules, both for the datalist element and for the options, they didn't work as well

Comment: the other suggestion i would give to you, is have a <select> place it over the input and make like a mashup of two objects overlaping, then use js to feed the data u click on the list into the input that will be under the <select>, if you are good at js, you could actually make the entier input as datalist withing js or jquery, but then are other scripts you can import in ur project if needed as a alternative to datalist for chrome.