# how to align datalist to right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't align the datalist option .

I tryied using `text-align: right` and `dir="rtl"` but both dosn't work.

since I'm using rtl direction I want the dropdown menu text aligned to the right not left also the arrow pointer should be aligned to the right

```html
      <form dir="rtl">
        <p>
          <label for="depart">اختار رقم</label><br />
          <input  list="myoptions"  autocomplete="on" />
          <datalist id="myoptions">
            <option dir="rtl" value="واحد"></option>
            <option value="اثنان"></option>
            <option value="ثلاثة"></option>
            <option value="اربعة"></option>
            <option value="خمسة"></option>
          </datalist>
        </p>
      </form>
```

I reported this issue as a bug to chrome :

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1287888

Comment: It seems to be a Chrome bug according to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191243/the-direction-of-the-datalists-options-does-not-change-in-chrome-browser)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier , You're right. I just tested it on firefox and works fine. anyway you saved my time ... thanks